# Materialize making slider images responsive

Tags: css, image, slider, materialize

I'm trying to develop a website with [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) and there is a slider in site. Materialize is responsive and working well at various resolutions. However, When I decrease the screen size, the slider width is decreasing as well (as it should be). But the image in it just getting cropped instead of scaling it to the size of the slider. I added the `responsive-img` class to the `img` but nothing changed.

**Slider code**

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider/slide_1.jpg">
            <div class="caption center-align">
                <h3>Eraltek Kurumsal</h3>
                <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Sitemize hoşgeldiniz</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="panoramic/panoramic.html">
                <img src="images/slider/slide_2.jpg">
                <div class="caption right-align">
                    <h3>Eraltek Mağaza</h3>
                    <h5 class="light yellow-text text-darken-1">360 derece mağaza turu için tıklayınız</h5>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider/slide_3.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider/slide_4.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/slider/slide_5.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue I can see that the default height isn't being correctly overridden everywhere.

Comment: I solved my issue as I had a carousel class on a higher element which was overflow hidden. So for me it's working now.

Answer (score 4):

Try to define in your css file

```
.slider .slides li img {
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try adding a css

> max-width : 100%;

to the `<img>` tag. Hope this will resolve the issue. Also don't forget to add `responsive-img` class to `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

Use img-responsive class with img tag.(you are using responsive-img, It is a bootstrap class. It is not working in materialize design)

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
   });
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">

 <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1">
                    <div class="caption center-align">
                        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2">
                    <div class="caption left-align">
                        <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no such class img-responsive in the materialize css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.slider li img{max-width:100%;height:auto;}
```